# replace switch-case statements with table-driven approach

Tags: php, refactoring, table-driven

I'm refactoring some existing code which converts between A and B using switch-case statements, it looks like this:

```
<?php
function string2num($s)
{
    switch($s){
        case 'AB':
            return 1;
        case 'CD':
        case 'GH':
            return 2;
        case 'EF':
            return 3;
        ...
    }
}

function num2String($n)
{    
    switch($n){
        case 1:
            return 'AB';
        case 2:
            return array('CD', 'GH');
        ...
    }

}
```

And it has too many cases, which leads to large amounts of code, Now, I want to do this with [table driven approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_table), but the problem is, when I build a table for `string2num()`: `$table = array('AB' => 1, 'CD' => 2, 'GH' => 2, 'EF' => 3, ...);`, I can't reuse the table in `num2String()`(I mean, `array_flip($table)`, then use it) since the the duplicate values in `$table` will become only one key when flipping. I know I can do that with 2 tables, someone have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the table like this:

```
$table = array(
    'AB' => 1,
    'CD' => 2,
    'GH' => 2,
    'EF' => 3,
);
```

You can retrieve multiple keys using [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function with optional search parameter, so

```
$keys = array_keys($table, 2);
```

will return

```
array('CD', 'GH');
```

Solution:

```
$table = array(
    'AB' => 1,
    'CD' => 2,
    'GH' => 2,
    'EF' => 3,
);

function string2num($table, $string) {
    if(isset($table[$string])) {
        return $table[$string]; 
    }
}

function num2String($table, $number) {    
    return array_keys($table, $number);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, never used `array_keys()` before:)